# How to turn bitlocker off on Surface Book

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bitlocker, microsoft-surface

After a fresh new OS install on my surface book, I noticed the following symbol on my hard drive in the explorer:
[image]

I then went to check on BitLocker in the control panel, and this is what it shows me: 
[image]

However, when I click on "Turn on BitLocker" it errors almost instantly with an error message saying [image]

So I tried to remove BitLocker (don't need it, and don't want it on my PC) and disabled the windows service (services.msc) and tried removing it through the "turn windows features on or off". Both of those yielded no results.

I then also checked in the disk management:
[image]

And it shows that it is BitLocker encrypted, even though it is not as the control panel just showed? What is going on here? This is a fresh install... Why is BitLocker even activated, how can I remove it from my system?

Comment: This indicates a problem with the TPM.  You use the Surface Book recovery image from Microsoft right?  Your question should be "how to turn on bitlocker" not turn it off, because it's actually already off.  The indication in Disk management is likely from your old installation and is an artifact of not deleting the partition and formatting the disk before installing Windows.

Comment: "Why is BitLocker even activated" - It's not activated see your first screenshot.

Comment: @Ramhound then why does Disk Management tell me it is activated?

Comment: @Ramhound I deleted every single partition and formated them when installing windows 10. I used an older ISO tho (took a while for all the windows updates to complete). Might try again with a newer ISO

Comment: Because the drive wasn't formatted before Windows was reinstall, so your previous installation which was protected by Bitlocker, left a header indicating it is encrypted.

Comment: You need to use the recovery image specifically offered by Microsoft otherwise you might have TPM driver issues.  Bitlocker is not currently activated, Disk Management, is erroneously picking up the Bitlocker header.  Although it's erroneously picking it up the header it's not actually a bug in Disk Mangement.

Comment: @Ramhound ok that makes somehow sense. How do I remove that header then?

Comment: By formatting the drive, and making sure no partitions exist, use disk part within WinRE to do this.  Be sure you also use the [recovery image](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage) from Microsoft for the Microsoft Book

Comment: @Ramhound So I would have to reinstall the OS one more time? And why do I need the recovery image for the surface book? I used to be able to install the OS manually with a default windows 10 ISO before on the surface book

Comment: "why do I need the recovery image for the surface book?" - It uses a .wim image with all the required drivers installed.  While I normally would suggest using the default ISO, due to the unique hardware, and Microsoft NOT publishing drivers for the device the same way other OEM's publish them, the best way to get the drivers is to use the recovery image.  I cannot guarantee your success if you don't use it.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah I see. I used these drivers for new installations with the default iso: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49497   They usually work fine.

Comment: @Ramhound if you post this as an answer, I will accept it and you can get the credits ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the powershell cmdlet:

```
Disable-BitLocker -Mountpoint "C:"
```

Followed by rebooting your PC.

Comment: Just tried that command, it says "BitLocker" is already performing an action on this drive... This Bitlocker sh*t is starting to fullfill each criteria there is for malware, and its preinstalled by default... What the f*ck is going on here?

Comment: Try going to Control Panel, BitLocker Drive Encryption, and turn off BitLocker there on C:.

Comment: read my question, I already tried that

Comment: My mistake, I missed that. Try open up gpedit.msc (Local Group Policy Editor) and go to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > BitLocker Drive Encryption and set any policies to Not Configured. Then reboot.

Comment: they are already all in the state "not configured", even checked its subfolders

Comment: @RononDex - "not configured" does not mean disable.  You should specifically set the configuration of policy you want if you want it.  "not configured" sometimes means enabled by default